# selecting distinct record using sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `People Job (ID, People ID, Post)`.

With sample data.

```
ID   People ID      Post

1    P1         Office Assistant

2    P2         Assistant Manager

3    P3         General Manager

4    P1         Officer

5    P2         Manager
```

I want to get records as follows.

```
ID    People ID     Post

3    P3          General Manager

4    P1          Officer

5    P2          Manager
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM People_Job GROUP BY People_ID`

Comment: I would go with the solution by @AmitSingh.  I don't know why it was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT PJ.*
FROM People_Job PJ
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT People_ID, MAX(ID) MAX_ID
    FROM People_Job
    GROUP BY People_ID
) T ON PJ.People_ID = T.People_ID AND PJ.ID = T.MAX_ID
```

Comment: It is the answer that I actually want. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure on your requirement, but in guess you want the data of the highest id for a specific people_id...
this should fit:

```
select * 
from People_Job
where id in (
    select max(id)
    from People_Job
    group by people_id
);
```

I just saw GriGrim's post - if you're running on large data his version should perform better...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `People Job` WHERE `ID People`>2 ORDER BY `ID People`
```

But your tables and column names should not contains spaces.